# Java spring boot Consider defining a bean of UserService in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to create my first JavaSpring Security Application but getting This error:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'de.JBR.mongo.models.UserService' in your configuration.
```

This is My Sprinboot application Class:

```
@ComponentScan({ "de.JBR.mongo.repositry", "de.JBR.mongo.api.models", "security.config", "security"})
@EnableMongoRepositories("de.JBR.mongo")
@SpringBootApplication
@AllArgsConstructor 
public class EssensManagerApplication {

    private final UserRepositry repositry;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EssensManagerApplication.class, args);
    
    }}
```

My de.JBR.mongo.models.UserService Class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService{

    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND = "Nutzer mit Name %s nicht gefunden";
    private final UserRepositry repositry;
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    
        return repositry.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND, username)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added a `@ComponentScan` and `de.JBR.mongo.models` is not in the list of packages, your service is not automatically created by Spring. So, either create a `@Bean` in a configuration file or add the package to the `@ComponentScan` list.